# Ignore duplicates when using INSERT in a Database with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `sob_tags_articles` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=112
```

And triing to save an object with Doctrine:

```
$sbTagsArticles = new SobTagsArticles();
$sbTagsArticles->article_id = $pubId;
$sbTagsArticles->tag_id = $tagId;
$sbTagsArticles->save();
```

But if record exists with the same $pubId and $tagId new record will be insertet with new PK.

How to do INSERT IGNORE into table with symfony?

```
$sbTagsArticles->isNew();
```

returns 1.

Thnx.

Comment: Why don't you use `(tag_id, article_id)` as the primary key?

Comment: @user274101: You do not need to change the title of a resolved question on StackOverflow. You should accept the correct answer instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
try
{
    $record->save();
}
catch(Doctrine_Exception $e)
{
    if($e->getErrorCode() !== $duplicateKeyCode)
    {
        /**
         * if its not the error code for a duplicate key 
         * value then rethrow the exception
         */
        throw $e;
    }

    /**
     * you might want to fetch the real record here instead 
     * so yure working with the persisted copy
     */
}
```

You should be ensuring that the same record doesnt exist on the application side not the SQL side. If you dont ever want the same article/tag combo to exist then add a unique index to `(article_id, tag_id)`. That should generate a mysql error which will in turn generate a doctrine exception that you can catch. There isnt an ignore flag for saves... You might be able to use one operating at a lower level of the DBAL (Doctrine_Query, Doctrine_Connection, etc..) but not directl from the ORM layer.

`Doctrine_Record::isNew()` will always return true if you have instantiated record asopposed to pulling it from the db otherwise it has way it has no way to know that the record is/isnt new.

Also why are you using the MyISAM storage engine? Im pretty sure this will actually result in more overhead when using Doctrine since it then needs to emulate constraints on the php side. Normally your schema would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sob_tags_articles` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `some_unique_constraint_name_1`
      FOREIGN KEY `article_id`
      REFERENCES `article` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `some_unique_constraint_name_2`
      FOREIGN KEY `tag_id`
      REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112
```

Comment: oh thanks! that schema would be great for this task, but I cannot modify table engine. And I've read that Doctrine is better and newer that Propel, so I use it. 

I've add an index. And now I need to catch Doctrine exception. Do you know how to do it? I use an ajax query to save records, so I don't need all this garbage be visible in firebug.

Comment: typical Try/Catch block with some logic to make sure its the error you expect... you might need to check the error code i dont remebr if Doctrine throws a generic Doctrine exception or something more specific. see above for example.

Comment: I seem to end up with the side effect of having the entity manager 'close'... Follows with Exception stating `The EntityManager is closed`. Gracefully handling individual exceptions with Doctrine is not really an option. You lose state. Subsequent statements are void. Better to re-factor and use a function on the repository, either using a transaction to check then insert or write something using DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE.

Comment: @ficuscr Im pretty sure that is specific to Doctrine2 as there is no EntityManager in Doctrine 1.x. (this Q/A was regarding 1.x). That said your argument and solution make sense, and could definitely be preferred.

Answer (score 6):

This is the actual code to be used

```
try
{
    $record->save();
}
catch(Doctrine_Connection_Exception $e)
{
    if($e->getPortableCode() != Doctrine::ERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        /**
         * if its not the error code for a duplicate key 
         * value then rethrow the exception
         */
        throw $e;
    }
    /**
     * you might want to fetch the real record here instead 
     * so yure working with the persisted copy
     */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could extend the SobTagsArticles object with a new save method, and check if the record already exists:

```
public function exists() {
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('sobtagsarticles ta')
    ->where('ta.tag_id = ? and ta.article_id = ?', array($this->getTagId(), $this->getArticleId()));

  if (!$result = $q->execute())
  {
    parent::save();
  }
}
```

This way the object will be saved only if it doesn't exist.

You could also set an unique index to your table like so:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `sb_tags_articles_unique` (`tag_id` ASC, `article_id` ASC)
```

Your schema would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sob_tags_articles` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `sb_tags_articles_unique` (`tag_id` ASC, `article_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `some_unique_constraint_name_1`
      FOREIGN KEY `article_id`
      REFERENCES `article` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `some_unique_constraint_name_2`
      FOREIGN KEY `tag_id`
      REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112
```

Comment: I think it is better not to query mysql once more to check if record exists.

Comment: Yes you can use memcached or redis queue instead