# Doctrine DBAL Insert if doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm using Symfony2-framework with Doctrine DBAL, and I'm inserting some data into MySql-database. Insert looks something like this(simplified):

```
$conn->insert('sometable', array(
        "col1"     => $data1,
        "col2"     => $data2,
        "col3"     => $data3
));
```

What I would like to achieve is the functionality like the ordinary sql-has. The ability to insert if doesn't exist, like: `INSERT IGNORE`. But is it possible to do such a thing with DBAL?

Note that I don't use objects here.

**Edit:** Please do note that I'm not using objects, but rather the depicted array-insert-method of DBAL.

**Edit2:** I tried to approach the problem with using the suggested try-catch, which seems to work quite well except for one thing. The db auto increments the primary key even if no new rows were added.
Here is the code that I used:

```
    try{
        $conn->insert('sometable', array(
            "col1"     => $data1,
            "col2"     => $data2,
            "col3"     => $data3
       ));
   } catch( \Exception $e) {
          switch (get_class($e)) {
               case 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException':
                   // No problems here. Just means that the row already existed.
                   break;
               default:
                   $this->get('logger')->error("(ERROR in ".__METHOD__.", @Row: ".(__LINE__)."): DB-error! error: ".$e->getMessage());
                   break;
          }
  }
```

And I also had to do a multiple row unique index for the table, because I have to check if all the columns are the same. i.e. if the whole row is the same as the one we are trying to insert.

So.. It works well otherwise, except that the auto increment value keeps rising up every time we try-insert-catch. I don't think it's a real problem, but it just feels stupid to waste numbers.. :D

Comment: Hi, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271026/ignore-duplicates-when-using-insert-in-a-database-with-symfony-and-doctrine

Comment: @Auris Please do note that I'm not using objects, but rather the depicted array-insert-method of DBAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this other than just doing a select query and try to retrieve the row, i.e:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE ....";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(); //or bindValue...
$stmt->execute();

$exists = $stmt->fetch();

if(!$exists) {
    // insert or whatever..
} else {
    // do nothing? 
}
```

Eventually you might be able to attach [Event](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) which would do that for you, but I'm not sure if that applies in your case.

Alternatively you could create an unique constraint and do a try/catch when inserting your data. Whenever the data is not unique, the database would return an error and you'd usually receive a `PDOException` although in Doctrine I think it's with a different name (check [exceptions](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Exception)). Just `catch` that exception and do nothing with it. Example:

```
try {
    $conn->insert('sometable', array(
        "col1"     => $data1,
        "col2"     => $data2,
        "col3"     => $data3
    ));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   // do nothing. 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been using so far, but with DBAL. First check and then insert if necessary, but I was hoping to have this in a same command. Then it would reduce the amount of code, and propably wouldn't take so much time as well. I've been reading the DBAL documentation but it.. Well.. Suck. I cannot find any information about doing the 'INSERT IGNORE' with DBAL.

Comment: Well, if you can set an `unique` column in your table, you could directly insert the data and do a `try{} catch(PDOException $e){}` or something like that. So whenever the data exists you will just `catch` the exception and do nothing with it?

Comment: Hmm.. That might work.. Have to try that later. Thanks for the tip!